# I want to create matter.js bodies at the press of a button and I'm running into errors

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I wanted to create a basic physics sandbox app using matter.js as the physics engine and p5.js for rendering. My idea was to spawn bodies on pressing of specific buttons (left key for bouncy body, right for heavy body, etc). I used this code for the key controlling:

```
if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    rubber2 = new Rubber(100,40,15) 
    rubber2.display()
}

rubber2.display();
```

Here is the `Rubber` class:

```
class Rubber {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    var options = {
      'restitution': 1.5,
      'density': 0.9,
      'friction': 1
    }
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r
    this.body = Bodies.circle(this.x, this.y, (this.r - 20) / 2, options)
    World.add(world, this.body);
  }
  
  display() {
    var rubberpos = this.body.position;
    push()
    translate(rubberpos.x, rubberpos.y);
    rectMode(CENTER)
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke("green");
    fill("yellow");
    ellipse(0, 0, this.r)
    pop()
  }
}
```

This is giving me errors like `rubber2 is not defined` or the `rubber2` body only displays while the key is held and it doesn't have any physics. Not displaying the ball at all does create the bodies but are invisible.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown seems pretty reasonable, so there's still not enough to really reproduce a problem you might be having. After a cleanup and turning it into a runnable example, I can offer:

```js
class Rubber {
  constructor(x, y, r, engine) {
    const options = {
      restitution: 1.5,
      density: 0.9,
      friction: 1,
    };
    this.body = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, r, options);
    Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, this.body);
  }
  
  display() {
    const {position: {x, y}, circleRadius: r} = this.body;
    push();
    translate(x, y);
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke("green");
    fill("yellow");
    ellipse(0, 0, r * 2);
    pop();
  }
}

let rubbers = [];
let engine;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 200);
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();
}

function draw() {
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    rubbers.push(new Rubber(mouseX, mouseY, 15, engine));
  }

  background(30);
  
  rubbers = rubbers.reduce((nextGen, e) => {
    const {position: {x, y}, circleRadius} = e.body;
    
    if (y + circleRadius <= height) {
      nextGen.push(e);
      e.display();
    }
    
    return nextGen;
  }, []);
  
  Matter.Engine.update(engine);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<p>Press the left arrow key to create a ball where the mouse is</p>
```