# Is there a way to make the balls generate at random positions within the canvas?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

```
function setup()
{
 createCanvas(800, 600);

//other code has been omitted
}

function generateRandomBalls() {

    var numRows = 5; // we have 4 rows, 5 including the top row
    var radius = 8;
    var startX = Math.random();
    var startY = Math.random();

    for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
            var xOffset = row * (sqrt(3) * radius);
            var yOffset = row * (radius * 3) / 2;
            var x = startX + xOffset;
            var y = startY - i * (radius * 3) + yOffset;

            var ball = Bodies.circle(x, y, 11, {
                restitution: 1,
                friction: 0.5,
                render: { fillStyle: 'red' }, // we set the color of the ball to red
                velocity: { x: 1, y: 2 },
                //collisionFilter: { group: 0x0002 }
            });
            Body.setAngle(ball, PI / 2); // we change the angle from -PI/2 to PI/2 to flip the triangle
            balls.push(ball);
        }
    }

    
    World.add(engine.world, balls);
}
```

The code should make the positions of the red balls are within the canvas at random but always remain with a grid-style (triangle style) shape, so that every time the game starts, it start at a random position of the canvas.

Comment: Use random numbers inside the loop to get random positions for each ball. Is that the effect you want? See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430806/6243352).

Comment: @ggorlen I have not seen the example yet, but i would want them to stick to the grid-style shape while it is at random positions.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: You mean move the whole grid around? I don't see how a grid and random positions are mutually compatible without further explanation.

Comment: [How to draw circles in a pyramid shape using p5js and matterjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77624416/how-to-draw-circles-in-a-pyramid-shape-using-p5js-and-matterjs) may be related. A number of people have been asking about how to create a pool/snooker triangle of balls in matter.js lately. Maybe an assignment or something.